# How Sign out to loginActivity when user inactive using common method for all activities in Android

Tags: android, user-inactivity

In my application i want to **sign out to loginActivity after 3 min when user inactive**

i am currently use this code to do that but in my application there is **more than 20 activities**
so without pasting this bunch of code every activity **i want common method** to do that,
 please help me

Here is the my  code

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Handler handler;
    private Runnable r;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);


        handler = new Handler();
        r = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();

                Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "Logged out after 3 minutes on inactivity.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        };

        startHandler();

    }

    public void stopHandler() {
        handler.removeCallbacks(r);

    }

    public void startHandler() {
        handler.postDelayed(r, 3 * 60 * 1000);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUserInteraction() {
        super.onUserInteraction();
        stopHandler();
        startHandler();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {

        stopHandler();
        super.onPause();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        startHandler();

        Log.d("onResume", "onResume_restartActivity");

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        stopHandler();

    }

}
```

Comment: Create user own custom BaseClassActviity. then Extend base activity where ever you want..

Comment: Am i want to use broadcastreceiver for that?

Comment: you need to use Service for this kind of things. It will be useful. If you use anything else or patch up your requirements after some time your app will become messy. so, it is advisable to use Service in your case

Comment: so where, i want to define handler it is also in the BaseActivity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a class like

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  // Write logic of logout same as what you wrote in HomeActivity
}
```

Now extend this `BaseActivity` to each activities which meant to show after login. like

```
public class HomeActivity extends BaseActivity {
  // Remove code related to logout from this class.
}
```

Comment: so where, i want to define handler, it is also in the BaseActivity?

Comment: @damithalahakoon Yes. Each line of code related to logout/ session will be inside BaseActivity

Answer (score 1):

You can make a BaseActivity Class here you can implement your functionality.
And then extend this activity with all your Activities.

Also you can use Application Class to control over the app